# No matching distribution found for intel-numpy

Tags: python-3.x, windows, numpy, pip

I'm trying to install Intel's `numpy` version through `pip` on Windows as described [on their website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-the-intel-distribution-for-python-and-intel-performance-libraries-with-pip-and).

```
> python -m pip install intel-numpy
Collecting intel-numpy
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement intel-numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for intel-numpy
```

I have 64-bit Python on Windows 10 and the main `numpy` package isn't installed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was my version of Python: `intel-numpy` is currently packaged for Python 3.6 and not 3.7. Installing Python 3.6 fixed it.